# Кличний відмінок імені Олег: Олегу чи Олеже?

Tags: вживання-слів, кличний-відмінок

Правопис української мови правильною формою подає лише варіант Олегу. Сайт slovnyk.ua, який містить дані із СУМу, уже пропонує вживати обидві форми. Що ж використовувати насправді?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Важливо**: у правописі відбулись зміни, а онлайн-словники ще не оновлені, дивіться [відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5764/240) пана stegetsj нижче.

У таких випадках я довіряю [онлайн-словнику Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), бачимо з цього ресурсу таку картину:

[image]

У ["Як ми говоримо"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53406/26264.html) пише:

> Стосовно вашого імені, пане Петрук, можна сказати таке: форма Олеже
>   (як і княже) – архаїчна і доречна в творах із життя минулих епох. У
>   сучасному мовленні нормативні форми такі: Олегу, князю. Називний
>   відмінок іменника, тобто Олег, неприйнятний в українському звертанні.

Тобто, у ситуаціях, де доречні архаїзми, можете вживати "Олеже", а в решті ситуацій послуговуйтесь звичною формою "Олегу".

Comment: *послуговуйтесь звичною формою "Олегу"*
-- у моєму розумінні, наприклад, звичною є саме форма "Олеже"

Comment: @xpoback тому відповідь відредагована й на початку стоїть посипання на іншу відповідь

Answer (score 7):

За правописом 2019 встановлена форма **Олеже**, але **Олегу** як неосновне.

> [§ 87. Кличний відмінок](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=95)
>
> Іменники другої відміни в кличному відмінку закінчуються на **-у** (**-ю**), **-е**.
>
> 1. Закінчення **-у** мають іменники твердої групи (зокрема із суфіксами **-ик**, **-ок**, **-к(о)**), іншомовні імена з основою на **г, к, х** і деякі іменники мішаної групи з основою на шиплячий приголосний (крім **ж**): *Пе́трику, Іва́нку, **Оле́же*** (й ***Оле́гу***), *ба́тьку, си́нку, пого́ничу, слуха́чу, това́ришу, робітнику́* (і *робітни́че*), *Дже́ку, Жа́ку, Лю́двігу, Фрі́дріху*; а також іменники *ді́ду, си́ну, та́ту*.

Однина, тверда група

| Відмінок | Відміна |
| --- | --- |
| Називний | [Олéг](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=140) |
| Родовий | Олéг-а |
| Давальний | Олéг-ові (-у) |
| Знахідний | Олéг-а |
| Орудний | Олéг-ом |
| Місцевий | Олéг-ові (-у) |
| **Кличний** | **Олéж-е (Олег-у)** |

Comment: Мені також дивно бачити форму кличного відмінку *«Олегу»*. Є щонайменше два подібні іменники, що закінчуються на `-г`, і кличний відмінок яких не викликає неоднозначностей: *бог* і *друг*.

Answer (score 0):

На ресурсі [СловникUA](https://slovnyk.ua/names.php?name=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3) вказана форма **Олегу**.

> Шановний Олегу!
>   Доброго дня, Олегу!

Comment: Схоже, що вони не встигають за новим правописом.